# how to read a date using input #

Tags: excel, vba

I am reading a file using input # format.

```
For read = 0 To 42
     Input #1, iData4
     If read = 21 Then Debug.Print iData4
Next read
```

the 21st field in the line is a date in format mm/dd/yyyy but it appears this method only reads mm.

So for example if the value in the original file is 10/12/2017 it reads in 10.

Almost like it is reading / as a delimiter. 
Any thoughts on this?
Changing 21 to 22 shows me that it reads the next column correctly. This only happens on columns with mm/dd/yyyy dates. I have another text field in the file that has a "/" that does not seem to affect the output.

I originally used "line input" instead of "input" for this project but I had data that contained a lot of commas which was throwing everything off when trying to split the line into variables.

Comment: How was the file created?  `Input #` is designed to read files that were created by `Write #`.  Can you upload a sample file that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: It looks like it is going to be an issue with quotes which identify a date... here is what the line looks like. The date is field 21 then I showed 2 fields after. ,8/18/2014,1,194 I don't know how thie file was created but I doubt it was using Write #

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with the limited information you have presented.  If I `Write` a file that includes a date field, I can `Input` the file without corruption. It may be that your file is not properly formatted, or that there is something elsewhere in your code that is causing the problem. But you have not provided any of that information.

Comment: Likely you will need a different tool to read that file. The date, within the file itself (eg if you open it with `NotePad`), should look like `#2014-08-18#`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thank you very much for your help! What I pasted above was how the date look in notepad and it does not contain #'s. I believe you are right and the answer to my question is a formatting issue and I will need to read the data using something other than "input". Line Input works well I just need to reconsider my original methodology. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If your data contains a lot of commas within text fields, and the fields are not qualified by text identifiers (eg `"`), you will need to do considerable clean-up to be able to process the data.  It can be almost impossible to determine if a comma is within a field, vs being used as a field separator, without those text qualifiers, depending on the actual data.